# Specflow generated code is incorrect?

Tags: specflow

I've recently started playing around with Specflow, and generating test cases based on the examples on their website[1]. However, the generated code doesn't compile. For example, the "Given a new bowling game" line, generates the following:

```
testRunner.Given("a new bowling game");
```

But, the signature for ITestRunner.Given() is:

```
Given(string text, string multilineTextArg, Table tableArg);
```

The same applies for When(), And() and Then(). It also seems that the binding step definitions require a `string` parameter as well, which does not appear to be documented.

Is anyone else having these same issues? I downloaded Specflow 1.6.1, and am using VS2005.

Thanks,
Daniel B.
[1] http://specflow.org/specflow/workflow.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "overloads" are done through extension methods, that are not supported in .NET 2.0 used by VS2005. So i think you have to upgrade to VS2008 at least to be able to use SpecFlow.

See also [SpecFlow forum entry related to VS2005](http://groups.google.com/group/specflow/browse_thread/thread/189ce792a5ea7086/8edfcb078dd28eb7?lnk=gst&q=VS2005#8edfcb078dd28eb7)

Comment: Thanks, Gaspar. We've upgraded to VS2010, and everything is working now.